# Can't call google sheets in MVC C# project but can in test project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am running a Google sheets API call, identical code works perfect in the unit test project and ran by the test manager.

When i put the same code into my class in the MVC5 project i get an error

**{"Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Apis.Sheets.v4, Version=1.29.1.988, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"Google.Apis.Sheets.v4, Version=1.29.1.988, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab"}**

Here is my code in my MVC Class

```
class GoogleSheetsAPi
{
 public void GetSheetData()
 {
   string[] Scopes = { 
   SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets,"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds" };

 }
}
```

The line above gets the error.

Comment: You've got a DLL version issue. Make sure you are compiling the MVC site with the same version of the Google DLL (`Google.Apis.Sheets.v4`) that you are deploying.

Comment: could you tell me the procedure to fix? i'm not to experience in .net

Comment: When you compile the code, the code base is associated with the signature of the Google DLL that is referenced by the MVC project. You need to make sure that the same DLL is deployed on the web server. It can't be a different DLL in any way-- even if the name is the same, it might have a different version number or public key. Ensure that the DLL is physically deployed in the right location and that other versions of the DLL do not exist on the web server.